# Fetch all sub-entities of all entities in CoreData

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

[image]

How do I select all `ProdusComandat` objects of all `ComenziActive` Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch the "ProdusComandat" objects without a predicate, that would give you 
all objects of that entity:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ProdusComandat"];
```

If you want only the "ProdusComandat" that are related to a "ComenziActive" object, add the
predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"comanda != NULL"];
request.predicate = predicate;
```